# Error while calling a .sql script from shell script

Tags: bash, oracle, shell, sqlplus

Folks,

I am trying to call an sql script with 1 parameter from shell script. My scripts are as follows

tab.sql

```
set lines 500
col file_name for a80

select file_name,bytes/1024/1024,maxbytes/1024/1024
  from dba_data_files
 where tablespace_name=upper('&TAB_NAME');
/
```

and my shell script is test.sh is

```
#!/bin/bash

LOC=`pwd`

echo -n "Enter the name of the Tablespace: "
read -r TAB_NAME

sqlplus "/ as sysdba" <<- EOF
@$LOC/tab.sql $TAB_NAME
EOF

exit
```

When I execute the script this is what I am getting

```
sh test.sh
Enter the name of the Tablespace: users

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Thu Nov 16 14:17:45 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected.
SQL> Enter value for tab_name:
SP2-0546: User requested Interrupt or EOF detected.
Enter value for tab_name:
SP2-0546: User requested Interrupt or EOF detected.
SQL> Disconnected
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong here? I searched on net regarding this SP2-0546 but didn't resolved my issue. I am using 11.2.0.4 db on OLE-6

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up [named](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_five.htm#SQPUG437) and [positional](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_five.htm#SQPUG444) substitution variables, and possibly confusing them with shell variables a bit too. You can refer to the argument passed on the SQL*Plus command line positionally:

```
select file_name,bytes/1024/1024,maxbytes/1024/1024
  from dba_data_files
 where tablespace_name=upper('&1');
/
```

If you wanted to you could define a named substitution variable; possibly overkill here but can be useful for clarity in bigger scripts:

```
define TAB_NAME=&1

select file_name,bytes/1024/1024,maxbytes/1024/1024
  from dba_data_files
 where tablespace_name=upper('&TAB_NAME');
/
```

or to simplify later references a bit:

```
define TAB_NAME=upper('&1')

select file_name,bytes/1024/1024,maxbytes/1024/1024
  from dba_data_files
 where tablespace_name=&TAB_NAME;
/
```

Note that in this version the reference to `&TAB_NAME` is *not* enclosed in single quotes, as they are applied during the substitution.

I can be helpful to `set verify on` while testing/debugging, then `set verify off` for real use to hide the noise. You might also find it useful to include the `-s` flag in the `sqlplus` call to hide the banner text. You don't even need a heredoc in this case, you can run the script directly from the command line too:

```
sqlplus -s "/ as sysdba" @$LOC/tab.sql $TAB_NAME
```

(Connecting as `sys` for routine queries isn't ideal; it would be better to have a normal user with privileges to see the data dictionary tables you need to query, but that's a different topic...)

Comment: Thanks guys for your response, let me check and I will get back to you on this.